# how is it that the `HttpClient` returns `NSURLSessionDataTask` but the `API method` that calls excepts ` { JSONResult, error in`

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, http

In my ServerAPI class I have this method:

```
func getState(name: String, completionHandler: (result: dto?, error: NSError?) -> Void) {

    let parameters = [String: AnyObject]()
    /* 1. Make the request */
    httpClient.taskForGETMethod(HttpClient.Methods.State, pathParameters: [name],  parameters: parameters) { JSONResult, error in

        /* 2. Send the desired value(s) to completion handler */
        if let error = error {
            completionHandler(result: nil, error: error)
        } else {
           ..
            completionHandler(result: state, error: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

which calls my HttpClient method:

```
func taskForGETMethod(method: String, pathParameters: [String], parameters: [String : AnyObject], completionHandler: (result: AnyObject!, error: NSError?) -> Void) -> NSURLSessionDataTask {

   ..
    /* 2. Make the request */
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) in

        /* GUARD: Was there an error? */
        guard (error == nil) else {
            print("There was an error with your request: \(error)")
            return
        }

       ...
        /* 3. Parse the data and use the data (happens in completion handler) */
        HttpClient.parseJSONWithCompletionHandler(data, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }

    /* 4. Start the request */
    task.resume()

    return task
}
```

Can you please explain how is it that the `HttpClient` returns `NSURLSessionDataTask` but the `API method` that calls excepts `{ JSONResult, error in` ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're confusing the last parameter ( the completion handler) with the return value (the data task). The return value is thrown away, otherwise it would have read `let task = httpClient.taskForGETMethod...`

Comment: i don't fully understand. the code works now without let 'task = '